# How can I update node version in docker container?

Tags: reactjs, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Now, I am developing some personal fullstack project using react, django, postgres and docker.
I first use node version 8 but now I try to use node version 16.
I tried like this.

```
FROM buildpack-deps:bullseye

ENV NODE_VERSION 16.18.0

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
```

But when I check node version in docker shell, it still shows node 8.17.0
How can I fix that?

I look forward to your great help.

Comment: buildpack-deps doesn't contain node and you don't install it in the Dockerfile you show, so how it gets in there is a mystery

Comment: How can I install latest version of node so that I can use latest react version?